# Where can I ask programming related questions not strictly related to coding errors?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask if some language feature is better than others, if other programmers feels the same as me about some aspect of certain programming aspects and so on?

On Stack Overflow, the questions simply get removed or similar, so which is the right Stack Exchange section?

[Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User) does not seem enough programming related, and I don't have idea where to go ask...

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @austin: **No.**

Comment: If you are asking for people to agree/disagree with you on any programming issue (or any issue for that matter), Stack Exchange sites are out. This is not the kind of question we are interested in.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn why not?  If they're discussion kind of questions, they'll get closed out downvoted, but other than those types, it seems like the place he/she is looking for.

Comment: @austin: because both types of proposed questions are discussions?

Comment: @Mat probably.  Without knowing the question or the context it's hard to tell.  In any case, Quora might be a good option if the question seems to open for discussion.

Comment: [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) accepts such questions. Sample: *[Why is Python better than PHP?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Python-better-than-PHP)*

Comment: Reddit (I think): http://www.reddit.com/r/programming

Comment: Hell I just had a question closed on programmers that I didn't think was a discussion type of question or asking for opinions. Apparently questions about why things are in a sorry state are also denied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) supports *somewhat* more subjective/philosophical questions than SO, but I doubt a "Do you feel the same way I do about X" will work on any Stack Exchange site. People still have quite a bit of trouble figuring out exactly what does or doesn't fall within scope at Programmers though (the last time I counted, a simple majority of questions were being closed) so you probably want to read its FAQ and attempt to phrase your questions to be constructive before asking something there.

To work on Stack Exchange in general, it still needs to be a question with some sort of real answer, not just inviting others to voice their agreement or disagreement with your rant.

To characterize the two, I'd give a sample question that I thing would be reasonably suitable for each (though others might disagree):

SO: I've written this code and it doesn't seem to be working out. Can anybody suggest a better way to write it?

P.SE: Several times, I've tried to write this type of code using the Visitor pattern, but it generally hasn't worked out well. Can anybody suggest an approach that's likely to work better in this type of situation?

Comment: thanks, that is what I was looking for!